# VBA Excel - Show row data in the UserForm based on the ID

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working with an UserForm with an UPDATE function. I just want to ask if how can I show the value in my UserForm? As of now, I only accomplished it by using the code below.

```
txtBox_ID.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value)
txtBox_lname.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("D8").Value)
txtBox_fname.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("D9").Value)
txtBox_mname.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("J8").Value)
txtBox_ext.Text = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("J9").Value)
```

As you can see the data is coming from **Results** sheet, but I want the UserForm to get the data in the **Data** sheet in which all the other data are located since I think it is needed in the find and update process.

Here's the sample [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17_Z2bPNHHh-Ogm0vPv9sG-fGfCCfnbswDsUS1LN3Pr0/edit?usp=sharing) so you can understand better. I'm just a newbie in this VBA thing and sorry for the poor English.

Comment: If you want data from `Data` sheet then just change name of sheet in code. replace `Results` with `Data` and change range accordingly.

Comment: @Harun24HR But how can it get the row with the specific value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work on my worksheet.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For r = 10 To lastrow
    If ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results").Range("D7").Value) Then
        txtBox_ID.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).Value
        txtBox_lname.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).Value
        txtBox_fname.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).Value
        txtBox_ext.Text = ws.Cells(r, 6).Value
        txtBox_mname.Text = ws.Cells(r, 7).Value
    End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can `Exit For` once you find a match

Comment: I'm going to put the `Exit For` before the `End If`, right?

Comment: Yes - it only applies if you find a match

Comment: @TimWilliams alright. Will modify it with `Exit For`. Thank you!

Comment: It's not required but might improve your code performance a tiny bit...

Comment: @TimWilliams noted with that! Thank you!